# Some pre-work when using langchain to connect to cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

I use cnosdb according to https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/latest/versatility/ai/LangChain.html, but the data preparation is not mentioned in the document, how should I prepare the data? Also, can I use langchain to generate cnosdb related sql?